# Back and logout using history.go() in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use the history.go() for the back and logout functions in my app as below

test.html

```
<a id="back" href="#"><img src="img/back.png" width="35px" />BACK</a>
```

test.js

```
'click #back': function() {     
            history.go("/dashboard");       
      }
```

This worked for part of my code, but now it does not work.Is there anything missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's a /dashboard in your history when you hit this? This seems like an odd way to make this feature. Are you using a router? Iron Router or Flow Router? If so, use their functions to navigate instead. If not, perhaps you should. Most meteor apps do.

Comment: Yes, I have /dashboard in my application and I use Iron Router too as below                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                `'click #go': function() {  
   Router.go("/search");  
  }`

Comment: OK, then you might be better off using Router.go("/dashboard"); Using history.go("/dashboard"); you not only need /dashboard in your app, it must be in your history for the page, you need to have been there before.